# Can't launch Aptana 3 / JDK issue?

Tags: java, ubuntu, aptana

I downloaded Aptana 3 on Ubuntu and also downloaded the jdk 8u65 but for some reason when I attempt to launch Aptana 3 it shows this

> Blockquote

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Aptana Studio 3. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/bryan/Downloads/Aptana_Studio_3/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH

> Blockquote

Comment: did you install the JDK?

Comment: Yes, I installed and extracted it@redFIVE

Comment: what happens when you type `java -version` in a terminal

Comment: `The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package> ` @redFIVE

Comment: Yeah you haven't installed java properly. There are plenty of guides telling you how to properly install java on Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but anyways I appreciate your time! I will look into it thanks @redFIVE

Comment: [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-oracle-java-6-7-or-8-ubuntu-14-04/) just in case anyone stulbled along the smae problem this link helped me

Comment: You should post the link as an answer to your question and explain what went wrong and how you fixed it